# Android: how to change image each touch

Tags: android, image, button, touch, uievent

I would like to change an image each time the user touches the screen. I would like to have user tap the screen and the image changes each time and at the 5th touch it would loop back to the original image with added text.

I have looked at

[How would I set an ImageButton to change only when my finger is touching it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028664/how-would-i-set-an-imagebutton-to-change-only-when-my-finger-is-touching-it)

I have tried both IUevents and StateListdrawable. I couldn't figure out how to actually change the image after each touch (anywhere in the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why can't you use the normal ImageView? Do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> picList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
// populate the list with the int value of the pictures in drawable.
picList.add(R.drawable.apple);
picList.add(R.drawable.horse);
//etc
int touches = 0;
int loop = 0;
ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_picture);
picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (touches < 4)
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(picList.get(touches));
                touches++;
           } else {
                touches = 0;
                loop = 1;
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(picList.get(touches));
           }
           if (loop = 1){
           // Create a TextView and set the text or make it in the xml with Visible="Gone" and make is visible here.
           }
    });
```

Comment: do you have more sample or completed sample to test this? =)

Comment: I just made this for you? It's not a sample. Can't you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create the Custom class which extends the ImageView now display this imageview to whole screen.

```
> First store the path/location of images into an array/list etc.
> In custom class implement the onTouch event.
> create the counter object in this custom class.
> now in onTouch check in down event that check the counter value with array size if counter==array.length()-1 then set counter as 0 otherwise increment in counter object.
> now get the path of the image and set into the imageview as background
```

Comment: Can you give me samples of them? =)